# Can't recieve push notifications on AVD?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-push-notification

I'm having some trouble receiving push notifications on my AVD devices. The app & notifications work without issue on physical devices so I know the AVD's are the issue. The app works perfectly on the AVD's (with the exception of the notifications) and consumes an API so I know its not a networking issue.

I've read through all similar posts on here and made changes without any success. I've created the following play store enabled AVD's:

```
Pixel 4 - Android API 33 Google Play | arm64 

Pixel 3a - Android API 33 Google Play | arm64
```

In addition I have tried both of the above with - Android API 33 Google API's.

From what I have read, both of these should be capable of receiving push notifications.

Interestingly, occasionally my app with log that a push notification had been received by the AVD and start to process it however the AVD shows no sign that it has receieved it.

Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Thanks